# Cannot use pgf-blur twice with XeLaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def} %this line does not matter
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[blur shadow](-2,0)circle(1);
        \draw[blur shadow](0,0)rectangle(3,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

leads to

[image]

Only XeLaTeX produces this. It is fine with LaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: This looks like an out-and-out bug in TikZ: have you reported it?

Comment: @JosephWright I guess I had a hard time telling it is Ti*k*Z's bug or pgf-blur's. Anycase, I just did it: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/375/

Answer (score 6):

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445321/2388

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{shadowblurcount}
\tikzset{
  /tikz/render blur shadow/.code={
   \stepcounter{shadowblurcount}%
    \pgfbs@savebb
    \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{\pgfbs@input@path}%
    \pgfbs@compute@shadow@bbox
    \pgfbs@process@rounding{\pgfbs@input@path}{\pgfbs@fadepath}%
    \pgfbs@apply@canvas@transform
    \colorlet{pstb@shadow@color}{white!\pgfbs@opacity!black}%
    \pgfdeclarefading{shadowfading\the\c@shadowblurcount}{\pgfbs@paint@fading}%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{black}%
    \pgfsetfading{shadowfading\the\c@shadowblurcount}%
       {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfbs@midx}{\pgfbs@midy}}}%
    \pgfbs@usebbox{fill}%
    \pgfbs@restorebb
  },
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blur shadow](-2,0)circle(1);
\draw[blur shadow](0,0)rectangle(3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug in pgf, but in pgf-blur. I found a working version here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files made by Andrew Stacey. This version fixes some other bugs, too.