# Fading, colored text (TikZ): Sentence won't change whilst compiling with XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, color, text

In general, I would like to have my sections in the same two-colored, fading style. I already found the TikZ and the \fadingtext command, which works very well whilst using "LaTeX" or "PDFlatex" for compiling.
Unfortunately, I need to use "XeLaTeX" for my document and I have the problem, that the name just duplicates. I also tried this minimal example and I have the same problem with the sentences. They're colored, but the sentences are just a copy of the first section name. For my sections I just need one fading color (from green to gray) and I also don't have numbered sections, the different colors in this example are just for better understanding.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzset{fading text/.style={}}

\newcommand\fadingtext[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name = fading letter]
    \node[text = transparent!0, inner xsep = 0pt, outer xsep = 0pt] {#2};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt] (textnode) {\phantom{#2}}; 
    \shade[path fading = fading letter, fading text, #1, fit fading = false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{fading text/.style = {left color = red, right color = green}}

\section{\fadingtext[left color = orange, right color = green]{Important}}
For testing the alignment: 
\fadingtext[left color = red, right color = blue]{Here is a colored sample sentence.}
And 
\fadingtext[left color = orange, right color = green]{This is another colored sentence.}

\section{\fadingtext[left color = red, right color = blue]{Very Important}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled text using: top picture) XeLaTeX and bottom picture) PDFlatex. Both sections and sentences are colored but with XeLaTeX the first sentence/word is always copied.]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: with xetex you would have to declare a new fading for each text. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445321/2388. Can't you use lualatex instead?

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer, I didn't know I can try Lualatex! Obviously I can use Lualatex and it works well.